# What escaping does PHP 7.4 `proc_open` do with an array argument to `$cmd`?

Tags: php, exec, spawn, php-7.4

In [the documentation for `proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), the text says

> As of PHP 7.4.0, cmd may be passed as array of command parameters. In this case the process will be opened directly (without going through a shell) and PHP will take care of any necessary argument escaping.

I can't see any reason to do any processing other than converting a associative array into a number-based list and right-trimming strings to remove NUL characters.

What "escaping" does the documentation mean? Is such "escaping" platform-specific?

Comment: On Linux no escaping is applied, the arguments are passed directly to execvp. Windows however does not have any concept of command line arguments, so an escaped string has to be assembled there.

Comment: If you're interested, this is the escaping applied on windows: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ed3f197f9f96449fcbb34ea11e61336cd666ac04/ext/standard/proc_open.c#L488-L544